# Set the local state using useEffect on Redux prop change

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect, use-state

I am new to React Redux and I am trying to `setState` on a prop change in Redux using a `useEffect` hook.

I have the following code:

```js
const DeploymentOverview = ({diagram, doSetDiagram}) => {
    const { diagram_id } = useParams()
    const [instances, setinstances] = useState(null)
    const [error, seterror] = useState([false, ''])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        GetDiagram(diagram_id).then(d => doSetDiagram(d)).catch(err => seterror([true, err]))
    }, [doSetDiagram])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (diagram) {
            if (diagram.instances) {
                let statusList = []
                diagram.instances.forEach(instance => {
                    InstanceStatus(instance.key)
                    .then(status => statusList.push(status))
                    .catch(err => seterror([true, err]))
                });
                setinstances(statusList)
            }
        }
    }, [diagram])

    return (
        <Container>
            {error[0] ? <Row><Col><Alert variant='danger'>{error[1]}</Alert></Col></Row> : null}
            {instances ? 
            <>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <h1>Deployment of diagram X</h1>
                        <p>There are currently {instances.length} instances associated to this deployment.</p>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Button onClick={setinstances(null)}><FcSynchronize/> refresh status</Button>
                <Table striped bordered hover>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Instance ID</th>
                                <th>Workflow</th>
                                <th>Workflow version</th>
                                <th>Jobs amount</th>
                                <th>Started</th>
                                <th>Ended</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {instances.map(instance => 
                            <tr>
                                <td>{ <StatusIcon status={instance.status}/> }</td>
                                <td>{instance.id}</td>
                                {/* <td>{instance.workflow.name}</td>
                                <td>{instance.workflow.version}</td> */}
                                {/* <td>{instance.jobs.length}</td> */}
                                <td>{instance.start}</td>
                                <td>{instance.end}</td>
                                <td><a href='/'>Details</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
                </> 
                
        : <Loader />}
            
        </Container>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    diagram: state.drawer.diagram
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    doSetDiagram: setDiagram
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DeploymentOverview)
```

What I want in the first useEffect is to set de Redux state of `diagram` (this works), then I have a other useEffect hook that will get a list from one of the diagrams attributes named `instances` next I loop over those `instances` and do a fetch to get the status of that instance and add this status to the `statusList`. Lastly I set the `instances` state using `setinstances(statusList)`

So now I expect the list of statusresults being set into `instances` and this is the case (also working?). But then the value is changed back to the initial value `null`...

[image: console]

In my console it's first shows null (ok, initial value), then the list (yes!) but then null again (huh?). I read on the internet and useEffect docs that the useEffect runs after every render, but I still don't understand why `instances` is set and then put back to it's initial state.

I am very curious what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple async operations you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (diagram) {
    if (diagram.instances) {
      Promise.all(
        diagram.instances.map((instance) =>
          InstanceStatus(instance.key)
        )
      )
        .then((instances) => setInstances(instances))
        .catch((err) => setError([true, err]));
    }
  }
}, [diagram]);
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const InstanceStatus = (num) => Promise.resolve(num + 5);
const useEffect = React.useEffect;
const App = ({ diagram }) => {
  const [instances, setInstances] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState([false, '']);
  //the exact same code from my answer:
  useEffect(() => {
    if (diagram) {
      if (diagram.instances) {
        Promise.all(
          diagram.instances.map((instance) =>
            InstanceStatus(instance.key)
          )
        )
          .then((instances) => setInstances(instances))
          .catch((err) => setError([true, err]));
      }
    }
  }, [diagram]);
  return (
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(instances, 2, undefined)}</pre>
  );
};
const diagram = {
  instances: [{ key: 1 }, { key: 2 }, { key: 3 }],
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App diagram={diagram} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

What you did wrong is the following:

```
diagram.instances.forEach(instance => {
  InstanceStatus(instance.key)//this is async
  //this executes later when the promise resolves
  //mutating status after it has been set does not 
  //re render your component
  .then(status => statusList.push(status))
  .catch(err => seterror([true, err]))
});
//this executes immediately so statusList is empty
setinstances(statusList)
```

Comment: Oh that is really cool! Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunatly `instances` is still null even with this code change. I've put a `console.log(instances)` after te `useEffect` and it shows null -> null -> filled array -> null. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @TobiasS I have added a working example using the exact code previously provided. Maybe there is a problem with `InstanceStatus` not returning a value

Comment: You are right, I've changed `<Button onClick={setinstances(null)}><FcSynchronize/> refresh status</Button>`  to `<Button onClick={() => setinstances(null)}><FcSynchronize/> refresh status</Button>` and instances array renders now. Thank you again for the good explanation and advice.